# Capturar valor de um campo do tipo email no angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Eu tenho o seguinte código HTML com AngularJS:

```
<html ng-app> 
    //...
    <form name="myForm2">
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="formData.email" required/>
        <span ng-show="!myForm2.email.$error.required && myForm2.email.$error.email && myForm2.email.$dirty">invalid email {{formData.email}}</span>
    </form>
    //...
</html>
```

O que eu pretendo é, se o utilizador preencher o campo e-mail errado, apareça a mensagem "invalid email valor_preenchido_no_campo".

Acontece que o código acima só retorna a mensagem "invalid email", não estou conseguindo capturar o valor do campo.

O que está errado no código acima?

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que ele esteja setando o valor de `formData.email` para `null` porque o valor do `input` é inválido. Vou tentar achar algo na documentação que comprove isso, aí posto uma resposta.

Comment: @gabrielhof penso que tens razão, fiz um teste e coloquei o e-mail correcto e o {{formData.email}} fora do span (porque ele fica oculto) e já aparece. Entretanto reparei que se colocar "email@dominio" ele considera certo e como podemos ver, não está.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não encontrei nenhuma parte da documentação do AngularJS que fale sobre isso, mas o comportamento padrão dele é **indefinir a propriedade vinculada ao input quando ele não possuir um valor válido**.

Isso é discutido nessa [issue do GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1412) e nessa [discussão no Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/8Fk-Ya6Juzo/discussion).

Ou seja, se `myForm2.email.$invalid` for verdadeiro, a variável `formData.email` será setada para `undefined`. Você pode visualizar isso nesse [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/3noL8hwp/).

### Solução no Angular 1.3.x

Caso você esteja usando a versão 1.3.x do Angular, existe uma solução utilizando [ng-model-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). Basta setar a propriedade `allowInvalid` para `true`:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}" ng-model="formData.email" required/>
```

[Esse exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/2d4q3ayo/) demonstra essa solução funcionando.